# Tensorflow 2 Object detection error when i am creating .record files

Tags: python, tensorflow

usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-i IMAGEDIR] [-o OUTPUTDIR] [-r RATIO] [-x]
generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /content/training_demo/images/train -l /content/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt
usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-i IMAGEDIR] [-o OUTPUTDIR] [-r RATIO] [-x]
generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /content/training_demo/images/test -l /content/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should provide more info for us to understand

Comment: okay I will add up more info to this

Comment: Hi @ibrahim46, Could you please provide standalone code to reproduce the issue. Thank You.